# Adding a new entity to collection in attached entity causes ConcurrencyException

Tags: entity-framework, dbcontext

I have simplified the code below to show the root of the problem. My real code is using GenericRepository and UnitOfWork pattern but I get the same exception with this simplified code too.
I am using Entity Framework 6, Code First

It uses the following POCO entities

```
public class Order 
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public virtual List<OrderProducts> OrderProducts {get;set;}
    ...

}

public class Product
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    ...
}

public class OrderProduct
{
    public int OrderId {get;set;}
    public int ProductId {get;set;}
    public int Quantity
    public virtual Order Order { get; set; }
    public virtual Product Product{ get; set; }
}

The user is able to create a new product and add it to the order products on the same screen.

//Pull an order from the database:
var existingOrder = db.Orders.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == inputModel.OrderId);

//Iterate the OrderProductInputModels (IMs) in the Inputmodel
foreach (var orderProductIM in inputModel.OrderProductIMs )
{
    var orderProduct = existingOrder.OrderProducts.SingleOrDefault(o => o.Id == orderProductIM.Id);

    //if its an existing order product (already in db)
    if (orderProduct != null)
    {
       //just update its property values
    }
    //if it has been added
    else 
    {
        //we need to create a new product first
        var newProduct= new Product() { <set some properties> };
        orderProduct= new OrderProduct()
        {
            Product=newProduct,
            Order=existingOrder
        }

        //Add the OrderProduct to the order
        existingOrder.OrderProducts.Add(orderProduct);
    }

db.SaveChanges();
```

On save changes, I get the following error.

[System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateConcurrencyException] = {"Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. Refresh ObjectStateManager entries."}

Why is this?

I expected entity framework to see that the existingOrders nested properties were newly added and unattached, update the order and create the new OrderProduct and Product.

Comment: Any of your entities using an optimistic concurrency token?

Comment: No I have not implemented this.

Answer (score 0):

Should it not be other way around in your if clause as you are checking for null ( then only it is a new order product else update. Issue is here:

```
 //if its an existing order product (already in db)
if (orderProduct == null)
{
   //just update its property values
}
//if it has been added
else 
{
```

Comment: Hi, good spot. However this was a problem when writing my question and not in my actual code. I have edited the code in my question.

Answer (score 0):

When you are looping around all the OrderProducts, you are constantly updating the database but the existingOrder object is not getting refreshed. Update that or add all the objects first and then update the database.

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved it by creating a test project and reverse code first engineering the database. Noticed that OrderProduct entity was not generated. On inspecting the database, the primary key was not set. Once I set the primary key in the database, the issue was resolved. Thanks for all the suggestions.